# PHP read and compare from database

Tags: php, database, csv, compare

Right now I'm using this script for reading a string from a csv file and displaying the matching result:

```
function bic_query($blz) {
$cdata = -1;
$fp = fopen(DIR_WS_INCLUDES . 'data/swift.csv', 'r');
while ($data = fgetcsv($fp, 1024, ",")) {
  if ($data[0] == $blz){
    $cdata = array ('blz' => $data[0],
                    'bic' => $data[7]);
                     return $cdata;
  }
}
}
...
$bic = $adata['bic'];
```

Instead of reading from the csv file, I want to read the values from the database and display the result a $bic variable. Thanks.

Comment: use mysqli_query function to achieve this

Comment: I know that, I'm not sure how to implement it

Comment: read in this link http://in1.php.net/mysqli_query or try it in w3schools site you may get good tutorial learn it

Answer (score -1):

Read [php.net's mysqli](https://www.php.net/mysqli). You need to establish connection to your database. I'd suggest making a class called MySQL and setting connection variables in a construct function, ex:

```
class MySQL {
    
    var $hostname;
    var $username;
    var $password;
    var $database;
    var $databaseLink;
    var $error;

    function __construct($port=3306) {
        $this->database = 'your database name';
        $this->username = 'username';
        $this->password = 'password';
        $this->hostname = 'hostname' . ':' . $port;

        $this->Connect();
     }

     public function Connect() {
         $this->databaseLink = mysql_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password);

     if(!$this->databaseLink) {
         $this->error = 'Could not connect: ' . mysql_error($this->databaseLink);
         return false;
     } else {
      return true;
    }
```

reading the manual will get you the rest, but this will give you a good idea on how to use it